# Rooted device check feature in wso2 Appmanager

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

In the WSO2 app-manager, is there any check so that we can check that the device is rooted or not.And if the device is found rooted than can we restrict the access to the Appstore from that device.If yes please tell how can we implement.Any suggestion will really be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You need to integrate WSO2 EMM with app manager and you have to enrol your device in EMM to install apps. Anyway when you enrol your device in EMM it will not allowed to enrol rooted devices. So there is no way rooted device to access the app manager and install apps. simply you don't have to explicitly implement this. This feature already there.:)

Comment: What if i don't want to install the EMM's android agent app, i just want to use the app-manager, then is it possible to check  for the rooted device??

Comment: Without EMM you can't do device operations like app install and uninstall. If you are connecting external EMM other that WSO2 one, then this is not possible.

Comment: But using WSO2 appmanager i was able to directly download the apps from the appstore link (https://<ip>:9443/store)

Comment: Anyway without rooted or not, restricting the access to store is not implemented. but you can't use device operations like install and uninstall if device is rooted. Anyway if you really want to prevent even browse and download apps using rooted devices, you can create a jira on this so that team will implement this in future

Comment: Thank u so much for the replies. And one more thing regarding this is if the authorized user download the app and then in future he shares that app through bluetooth or some app(like shareit) to an unauthorized user, then is it possible to restrict the app sharing.If possible than how can it be achieved.And in which platform it can be achieved(In WSO2 App-manager or EMM or Both).

Comment: if users are enrolled with EMM, this can be achieved. you can create black list policy. black list policy will monitor the devices for app list and hide applications that are not allowed on device. anyway this feature is available on next release.